# Matlab, how to change audio device for output

Tags: matlab

I want to be able to specify which audio output the sound to be played. 
Using audioDeviceWriter I am able to get the device info, but I don't know how I can change the output to a specific device. I try .Device(index) but that doesn't work. Please help.

```
fs = 44100;
T = 1/fs;
t = [0:T:2];

f1 = 250;
omega1 = 2*pi*f1;

phi = 2*pi *0.75;
x1 = cos(omega1*t +phi);

deviceWriter = audioDeviceWriter(fs);
devices = getAudioDevices(deviceWriter);
% I wish to change the audio device here between built-in and my sound card.
deviceWriter.Device(3)

sound(0.9*x1, fs)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get your code to work by setting the [`'Device'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/ref/audiodevicewriter-system-object.html#mw_9d2359d9-2776-40b5-ac26-1c103c417743) property to `devices{3}`, setting the [`'SupportVariableSizeInput'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/ref/audiodevicewriter-system-object.html#mw_6dfedd2e-9eab-476b-9904-4e4ea2de4c0f) property to `true`, and converting your audio signal `x1` to a column vector (using the [colon operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html)) before passing it to the `deviceWriter` obj to play it:

```
% Data same as above...

deviceWriter = audioDeviceWriter(fs);
devices = getAudioDevices(deviceWriter);
deviceWriter.Device = devices{3};
deviceWriter.SupportVariableSizeInput = true;

deviceWriter(x1(:));
```